# 'const char*' and 'WCHAR*'

Tags: c++

It's my first time making an external gamehacking application, and I'm having tourble with something.

My issue: Cannot convert 'const char*' to 'WCHAR*' in argument passing.

I already tried to change the character set to multibyte, but its still showning an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

HANDLE hProc = NULL;
DWORD pID;

bool attachProc(char* procName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry32;
    procEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    
    auto hProcSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hProcSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        std::cout << "Snapshot failed :((" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    while (Process32Next(hProcSnap, &procEntry32))
    {
        std::cout << procEntry32.szExeFile << std::endl;

        if (!strcmp(procName, procEntry32.szExeFile)) //ERROR RIGHT THERE
        {
            std::cout << "Process found: " << procEntry32.szExeFile << " Process id: " << procEntry32.th32ProcessID << std::endl;
            hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procEntry32.th32ProcessID);
            pID = procEntry32.th32ProcessID;

            if (hProc == NULL)
            {
                std::cout << "Process handling failed." << std::endl;
            }

            CloseHandle(hProcSnap);
            return true;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Couldn't find " << procName << " in the process snapshot." << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(hProcSnap);
    return false;
}

template <class dataType>
void wpm(dataType valToWrite, DWORD addressToWrite) {
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (PVOID)addressToWrite, &valToWrite, sizeof(dataType), 0);
}

template <class dataType>
void rpm(DWORD addressToRead)
{
    dataType rpmBuffer;

    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (PVOID)addressToRead, rpmBuffer, sizeof(dataType), 0);

    return rpmBuffer;
}

int main()
{

    DWORD memoryAddress;
    attachProc((char*)"hl2.exe");
}
```

Tysm, i hope u guys can help me out with this.

Comment: Nothing there is wrong. It seem you missed something. Quote the full error messages including message and warnings prior the error.

Comment: You should not be getting the error you claim at the place you claim. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], and copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output into the question.

Comment: Beyond that, I'll bet you build with the macro `UNICODE` defined, which means all standard Windows API function will default to the wide-character variants (using `WCHAR` instead of `char`). If you want to mix standard C++ functions with Windows API functions then you need to either remove the `UNICODE` macro when building, or explicitly use the `A` suffixed functions (which uses narrow-character `char` instead).

Comment: First of all why are returning something in the function ```rpm``` whilst it has no data-type assigned to it?

Second, casting "hl2.exe" into ```char*``` is utterly useless because it's already a ```const char*```

Third, ```PROCESSENTRY32``` is a structure whence the variable ```szExeFile``` is a ```char[]``` type. I tried myself and it works without problem. I think it's most likely a bug, unless you use ```PROCESSENTRY32W```, which I doubt.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If the error was caused by having a UNICODE build (i.e. using `PROCESSENTRY32W`), then the error would be the "other way round" - converting `WCHAR*` to `const char*`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You **should** be getting an error. First, `const char*` could be compatible with `const WCHAR*` and not `WCHAR*`.

Another thing, usually, in Windows, WCHAR characters stand for `utf-16` characters, and `ascii` characters are not the same as `utf-16`. Windows has a built-in function converting from `utf-8` or `ascii` to `utf-16`, as follows:

```cpp
    const auto result = MultiByteToWideChar(
        CP_ACP,
        MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
        yourStringHere,
        yourStringSizeHere
        yourTargetStringHere,
        yourTargetStringSizeHere
    );
```

And, the C-standard library has an equivalent implementation -

```cpp
std::mbstowcs(wchar_t* dst, const char* src, std::size_t len);
```